# Google Calendar API v3 setRecurrence

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I'm new to the Google API (v3) and I am trying to create a recurring event.

I can authorize the user and create an event, but recurrence just won't take. I'm not certain how to pass the recurrence array to the method setRecurrence().

```
$event->setRecurrence(array('RRULE'=>'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20111205T000000Z'));
```

Anyone know the answer to this? TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this issue is to set the timezone for the event prior to setting the recurrence.

```
require_once "./google-api-php-client-read-only/src/apiClient.php";
require_once "./google-api-php-client-read-only/src/contrib/apiCalendarService.php";

$event = new Event();
$event->setSummary('Event Name');

$event->setLocation('Event Address;City, State Zip);

$start = new EventDateTime();
$start->setDateTime('2011-12-25 10:00:00:000 -0050');
$start->setTimeZone('America/New_York');

$event->setStart($start);

$end = new EventDateTime();
$end->setDateTime('2011-12-25 13:00:00:000 -0050');
$end->setTimeZone('America/New_York');

$event->setEnd($end);

$event->setRecurrence(array('RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20111229T130000Z;'));

$createdEvent = $service->events->insert('primary', $event);
```

Comment: Mind the typo in this answer. Needs a ' adding to `$event->setLocation('Event Address;City, State Zip);`

Answer (score 0):

Why `RRULE:` again in the value? The value should be formatted according to https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2445

Comment: It does not work with or without RRULE in the value. I suspect the formatting is completely wrong. My hours of Googling the answers has yielded no results, the documentation for their php classes is slim, and sample code for the calendar API is nil.

Comment: Actually the syntax of that field predates Google Calendar and maybe even PHP. See e.g. iCalendar. http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2445

Comment: Try creating a recurrence rule with "newReccurrence" (instead of `array`), then assigning it somehow, maybe with setRecurrence.

Comment: The wrapper class provided by Google, Event() does not contain a newRecurrence() method. The parameter I'm trying to pass to Event->setRecurrence($arParameter) must be passed as an array of strings. However, it isn't clear how to format the string. The response does not throw errors, and the post body sent to Google appears to be well-formatted. I'll look at the link you provided to see if it sheds any light. The search goes on!

Comment: And if you pass a plain array instead of the associative array?